# "something that you wear on your hands in the winter that rhymes with kittens"

Tags: word-order, relative-clauses, antecedents

Can anyone tell me which sentence below is correct?

> I'm thinking of something that you wear on your hands in the winter that rhymes with kittens.

v.s

> I'm thinking of something that you wear on your hands and rhymes with kittens in the winter.

I doubted the first sentence because "that rhymes with kittens" should modify the word"something". However, it was placed after "winter" , which I feel it is incorrect.
I wrote the second sentence and am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: No the second sentence doesn't work. It means the "something" rhymes with kittens in the winter. Mittens, the word alluded to, doesn't have to rhyme with kittens only in the winter. It rhymes any day of the week, all year long. The first sentence, though with a separation between the relative clause and its antecedent, works fine.

Comment: By the way, I just took a quick look at your past questions. This question here is fine, but some of your past questions should show more research effort on your part. You should tell us what you think and what research if any you have done. Also you have not accepted any answers but some of your questions have received pretty good answers worth accepting. You don't need to write "thank you" comments. Voting on and accepting answers are the ways to express gratitude around here.